# How to reduce the pink tone of the skin while increasing global saturation in RawTherapee?

Tags: saturation, rawtherapee, skin-tones

I like to increase the saturation a little bit to vivid the colours of the landscape, plants/flowers or clothes. But doing this with a (caucasian) human in the photo quickly makes the skin too pink.

Is there any easy technique to increase the saturation except for the skin tones?
I have more or less zero knowledge with the tones and HSV tools.

Comment: Assuming your color temperature and white balance settings closely match the illuminant used, if you play around with a Hue-Saturation-Luminance/Value/Brightness tool for very long you'll discover that human skin (of all ethnicities) is most affected by the *orange* color band. The *red* band is also highly influential, but *orange* will have the most impact on skin tones. If orange adjustments don't do much to skin tones, it probably means your CT is set to a lower value than your light source's output, your magenta ←→ green setting is too far into magenta, or your light source has a low CRI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything wrong with checking the "Protect skin-tones" box in the "Vibrance" section in the "Color" tab?  That's where I'd raise saturation normally.

Comment: Indeed, thx! The skin-tones protection seems to limit very much the saturation in the red colours though (which make sense), I suppose you need to work in the HSV to saturate the reds while still excluding the skin

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop, by placing a hue and saturation adjustment layer, the change can be global (Master) throughout the image or by color by choosing it from the master dropdown menu. [Adobe Photoshop Hue/Saturation adjustment layer](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/adjusting-hue-saturation.html/#specify_the_range_of_colors_adjusted_in_the_hue_saturation_adjustment)

[image: huesat]

Starting from [this image](https://unsplash.com/photos/DItYlc26zVI), the image on the left is the original, and the one on the right is the retouching only increasing the saturation of yellows(minimally), greens, cyans, and blues:

[image]